# Electric potential Vss (negative) in Diodes, Mosfets and BJTs

Tags: electricity

I am studying electronics and I am in confusion with the way the book uses the Vss (negative) electric potential.
In particular, let's say, I can imagine Vcc or Vdd as the electric potential obtained by a voltage generator whose positive electric potential is 5 V and the negative potential 0 V.
If we talk about Vss (negative electric potential), how can I immagine the voltage generator which generates this negative electric potential? I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a 9V battery. Depending on which terminal you decide to set the multimeter reference with the black probe, you measure 9V or -9V. Take two batteries, put them in series, and now you have 18V battery. Or -18V battery. Or +/- 9V battery. It depends what you select as the 0V reference. Same thing with a 1 meter stick. If it is 1m above ground, halway buried into ground, or completely buried into ground, it is still 1 meter stick, you just have to choose the reference ground level.

Comment: So can you please draw me if you can the voltage generator?

Comment: @Angelo, have you never seen a 9 V battery before?  How would a drawing of one help your understanding?

Comment: I have solved my doubt. Thank you.